# GitHub triggers pull_request but it is not expected

Tags: github-actions

I have a workflow, *main.yml*:

```yaml
name: Build Main
on:
  push:
    branches: main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, labeled]
```

I also have this other one, *feature.yml*:

```yaml
name: Build Feature

on:
  push:
    branches: feature/**
```

When I'm on a feature branch (feature/NN-my-feature), and I push a commit from Visual Studio Code, both the workflows run.
Looking at the Actions in GitHub, the main.yml is triggered by a "pull_request".
I don't understand why/how the pull_request on "main" is triggered.

Comment: Do you have an open pull request on that feature branch?

Comment: yes, a Draft pull request on the feature branch, not on _main_ branch.

Comment: if the base branch of PR is main, both workflows will run